# windows 8.1 not available in grub after installing ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, windows-8

I have win7, win8.1 and Ubuntu installed, each one in a separate partition (win 8.1 is in a separate hard drive). windows 7 and Ubuntu are booted in Grub but not win8. before installing Ubuntu, secure boot was disabled in win8.1 but there was no *UEFI firmware settings* anywhere in PC setting.

after installing Ubuntu, I tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

but I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package boot-repair
```

since I am a newbie in all theses, kindly write any answers in "for dummies" format!

Answer (score 0):

Download the boot repair cd, boot from it and just accept the default settings. Thats how i fixed grub in my ubuntu and windows 8.1 setup.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following 4 commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair